# Salt Minion Error: Unable to sign_in to master: Attempt to authenticate with the salt master failed with timeout error

Tags: salt-stack

I have a salt master and a minion running in VirturalBox using vagrant.
Minion is not able to connect to the master, when I execute 'salt-call test.version' it returns error 'Unable to sign_in to master: Attempt to authenticate with the salt master failed with timeout error':

```
[root@infbitgitl01v ~]# salt-call test.version
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Grains refresh requested. Refreshing grains.
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'core' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'disks' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'extra' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'lvm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'mdadm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'minion_process' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'opts' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] Override  __utils__: <module 'salt.loaded.int.grains.zfs' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/grains/zfs.py'>
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] Elapsed time getting FQDNs: 0.07333755493164062 seconds
[DEBUG   ] The `lspci` binary is not available on the system. GPU grains will not be available.
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded zfs.is_supported
[DEBUG   ] Connecting to master. Attempt 1 of 1
[DEBUG   ] Master URI: tcp://192.168.56.10:4506
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncAuth for ('/etc/salt/pki/minion', 'infbitgitl01v.loc.geoplace.co.uk', 'tcp://192.168.56.10:4506')
[DEBUG   ] Generated random reconnect delay between '1000ms' and '11000ms' (5982)
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl to '5982ms'
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl_max to '11000ms'
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_key: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt._get_key_with_evict: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_182b8c2f71_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_182b8c2f71_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_pub_key: Loading public key
[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncReqChannel instance
Unable to sign_in to master: Attempt to authenticate with the salt master failed with timeout error
```

On salt-master I tried salt '*' test.version and it just hangs at:

```
[root@devmaster ~]# salt '*' test.version
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Changed git to gitfs in master opts' fileserver_backend list
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: devmaster
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncReqChannel instance
```

On salt-master logs (/var/logs/salt) I see the following error:

```
2023-07-04 14:36:00,805 [salt.utils.process:1002][ERROR   ][8889] An un-handled exception from the multiprocessing process 'MWorker' was caught:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/utils/process.py", line 993, in wrapped_run_func
    return run_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/master.py", line 1142, in run
    self.__bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/master.py", line 994, in __bind
    self._handle_payload, io_loop=self.io_loop
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/channel/server.py", line 101, in post_fork
    self.transport.post_fork(self.handle_message, io_loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/transport/zeromq.py", line 418, in post_fork
    self.stream = zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream(self._socket, io_loop=io_loop)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._init_io_state()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 528, in _init_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_handler(self.socket, self._handle_events, self._state)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/ext/tornado/ioloop.py", line 730, in add_handler
    self._impl.register(fd, events | self.ERROR)
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

and

```
2023-07-04 15:05:34,414 [salt.utils.process:1002][ERROR   ][27087] An un-handled exception from the multiprocessing process 'PubServerChannel._publish_daemon' was caught:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/utils/process.py", line 993, in wrapped_run_func
    return run_func()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/channel/server.py", line 777, in _publish_daemon
    self.transport.publish_daemon(self.publish_payload, self.presence_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/transport/zeromq.py", line 719, in publish_daemon
    monitor.start_io_loop(ioloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/transport/zeromq.py", line 645, in start_io_loop
    self._monitor_socket, io_loop=io_loop
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._init_io_state()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 528, in _init_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_handler(self.socket, self._handle_events, self._state)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/ext/tornado/ioloop.py", line 730, in add_handler
    self._impl.register(fd, events | self.ERROR)
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

and

```
2023-07-04 15:05:24,498 [salt.utils.process:1002][ERROR   ][26725] An un-handled exception from the multiprocessing process 'PubServerChannel._publish_daemon' was caught:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/utils/process.py", line 993, in wrapped_run_func
    return run_func()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/channel/server.py", line 777, in _publish_daemon
    self.transport.publish_daemon(self.publish_payload, self.presence_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/transport/zeromq.py", line 719, in publish_daemon
    monitor.start_io_loop(ioloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/transport/zeromq.py", line 645, in start_io_loop
    self._monitor_socket, io_loop=io_loop
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._init_io_state()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 528, in _init_io_state
    self.io_loop.add_handler(self.socket, self._handle_events, self._state)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/ext/tornado/ioloop.py", line 730, in add_handler
    self._impl.register(fd, events | self.ERROR)
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

This setup worked last week, I have not made any changes to salt versions. Salt version si salt 3005+0na.9d3b3b7 (I wasn't expecting this long number as well).

Both salt-master and salt-minion can ping each other.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

I have tried to destroy and rebuild salt-master and minion. Did a yum updae on salt-master. Nothing worked so far.